.gltf 3D object imported as empty, can't see it
When I import the 3D object that I made of a map using QGIS, it gets imported as an empty class in Blender. I don't think the file is corrupted as it is easily viewable in Microsoft 3D Viewer, so I'm guessing it's something on Blender's end. How can I get this file properly into Blender?

What do you mean by "an empty class"? Please add an image of your Blender window which you can do via the Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question and add the image to it.
